# Popular Song in a Rebus

Tags: rebus

[image]
If anyone has any tips on how to make future rebuses better, please tell me.

Hopefully this doesn't take too long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is

> *Believer* from the album Evolve by Imagine Dragons. The left is Cardi B and Bobby Vee on a bed, so B + lie + Vee + are [for equals, as Riley notes] = Believer. As Riley points out, the backward E is in the style of the name *Evolve* on the album cover. The right side is clearly imagining a dragon. The 4 is the peak rank of the song on the US *Billboard* Hot 100. Riley notes that 4 is also the number of the song in the album.

Comment: The backwards E is on the album cover for Evolve. The equals is probably "are", so that makes "B lie Vee are"?

Comment: I think you are correct, but what about the number 4?

Comment: Believer is the fourth track on the album.

Comment: No problem. I had already been thinking about the same answer, but I didn't know who the people were.